# Using preprocess hook on specific node type in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-hooks, drupal-templates

I've had success using preprocess page hooks such as:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page__node_front(&$variables) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page__node_12(&$variables) {
    ...
}
```

which correlate with custom templates named page--front.html.twig and page--12.html.twig, respectively.

I'm trying to implement the same hook and template pairing for a content type called Video. I understand that there is a difference in that my examples have been custom templates for specific pages while my goal is a custom template for an entire content type, but I got a custom template called node--video.html.twig that works as a template for all video pages. However when I try to write a hook based on this template name:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node__video(&$variables) {
    ...
}
```

this does not work. I think that I either can't define a hook like this, or I'm just naming it incorrectly. I found a couple threads somewhat relating to this such as [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1692202) that seem to imply that I need to define a hook for all nodes and then write an if statement that handles each type separately.
So.......

***Final Question***: Can I define a hook for an entire content type, and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally `template_preprocess_node__NODE_TYPE` and `template_preprocess_node__NODE_TYPE__VIEW_MODE` should work just fine **now**. As I'm always using specific node type preprocess hooks just like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use condition within the preprocessor to get the node type and then either do your logic within, or invoke another function.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  switch ($variables['node']->getType()) {
    case "video":
      // ...
    break;
    case "something_else":
      // ...
    break;
  }
}
```

You could in theory emulate what you are trying to achieve by trying to invoke a function named `mytheme_preprocess_node__" . $variables['node']->getType()` if it exists, but is too much fuss without a clear benefit.

Answer (score 6):

In drupal 7 from zen template I used to use this generic solution. I think it is still a viable solution on drupal 8:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  ...
  // Add global modification that works for all node type
  $function = __FUNCTION__ . '__' . $variables['node']->getType();
  // Each node type can have its own specific function
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($variables, $hook);
  } 
  ...
}
```

You can then now add preprocess function that will only works for you node type.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node__video(&$variables) {
    ...
}
```

Instead of having one big function, each node type's preprocess logic has its own function. It's better for maintainability.